# Magento Command line script Class 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: magento, soap

I am trying to run a script from commandline to call a method in a Model, which involves the class **SoapClient** But come up with the error message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in ....
```

Line which has the error is

```
$client = new SoapClient($this->_soapUrl);
```

I run the same process through web using a test route and it works.

Checked PHPINFO and it says

```
Soap Client  enabled
Soap Server  enabled
```

How can I include the SoapClient Class to the script or what can be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line PHP uses different php.ini. Find out which php.ini file is used in PHP CLI and make sure the Soap extension is loaded there as well.

Comment: Yep, I use wamp server, that commandline php.ini was at wamp/bin/php5.3.13/php.ini. enabling soap extension from there solved the problem. Thanks.